# Adding PTR to DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to create a PTR records for a domain, but I'm a bit confused.

I've looked at PTR records on another server with Plesk installed and the records contained the IP for server and then /24 afterwards. What is the /24 and should I use /24 (or something else)?

How do I found that out?

Comment: Interesting, but off-topic. Nominated for webmasters (it sounds appropriate).

Comment: Actually, it's best suited for serverfault.

Comment: You dont create PTR records for a domain, you create them for a subnet. 1.2.3.4 can have a PTR record of xyz.domain.com and 1.2.3.5 can have a PTR record of bleh.blah.com. It's not tied up to domains.

Comment: the /24 is the bits for the subnet mask. Meaning 255.255.255.0 for your particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PTR records are a special case.  Whoever supplies your IP addresses (usually your host/ISP), must do one of the following:

- Set up your reverse DNS entries on their DNS servers.
- Delegate authority" for your reverse DNS entries to your DNS servers.

This has to do with the unique nature in which reverse DNS is resolved.

I would contact your host to resolve this and disable/remove the PTR records on the Plesk system.

Another note about reverse DNS is that it is a 1:1 mapping.  You should not have multiple PTR records mapping an IP to a domain.  In contrast, you can have multiple A records mapping different domains to the same IP.

Here is a good resource on PTRs.

http://www.crucialp.com/resources/tutorials/web-hosting/how-reverse-dns-works-rdns.php